# Trouble with Locking

Tags: android

I want to lock the screen of the app on button click

I have written the code as

```
public class MainActivity extends DeviceAdminReceiver{


public void makeTest()
{
    System.out.println("Entered Main Class");
}
public class Controller extends Activity {

static final int RESULT_ENABLE = 1;
Button powerOff;
int amountOfTime =20*1000;
Context context = this;
DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
ActivityManager mAM;
ComponentName mDeviceAdminSample;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    System.out.println("Enterd inner Class");
    mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    mAM = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    mDeviceAdminSample = new ComponentName( Controller.this,MainActivity.class);


    powerOff = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    powerOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              System.out.println("Entered Button Click");
              mDPM.lockNow();


                Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,
                        mDeviceAdminSample);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                        "Additional text explaining why this needs to be added.");
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_ENABLE);


        }
    });


}
```

It showing certain errors the logcat output is

```
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.screenlock/com.example.screenlock.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.screenlock.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.screenlock.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1039)
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
 01-15 15:51:12.043: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: The problem is in your log: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.screenlock.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does `DeviceAdminReceiver` extend `Activity` ? if not the log suggests that is your problem.

EDIT : as can be seen [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html) `DeviceAdminReceiver` is a `BroadcastReciever` which is not an `Activity`. your `MainActivity` class must extend `Activity` or a subclass of `Activity` so the system can run it.

Comment: DeviceAdminReceiver is not an `Activity` but a `BroadcastReciever` as can be seen [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html). your `MainActivity` does not extend `Activity` and so cannot run.

Comment: @abcd see edited answer. extend `Activity` instead of `DeviceAdminReceiver` and you'll be set.

Comment: @abcd that's weird, it's right there in my answer after "EDIT:". anyway the solution is to extend `Activity` instead of `DeviceAdminReceiver`.